# Adding Hours to Date & Time in Linux

Tags: linux, date

I am trying to add 5 hours to a date & time in Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.03) using the 'date' command.  I get different results if I specify a date vs if I don't.

Example 1:  I want to add 5 hours to a specific date:

```
  [12:45:25 ~]$ date -d "2019-12-08 12:16:45 +5 hours"

  Sun Dec  8 03:16:45 EST 2019
```

But the result is 9 hours BEFORE the specified date and time.  I was expecting to have a date of 12/8 and time of 17:16:45.

Example 2:  I add 5 hours to the system date:

```
  [12:45:37 ~]$ date -d "+5 hours"

  Sun Dec  8 17:46:02 EST 2019
```

This result is correct and as I expected.

I want to use this in a bash script and can't determine what I am doing incorrectly that I get these different results.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around a bit it seems like specifying the timezone with no spaces achieves what you're looking for:

```
date -d "2019-12-08 11:16:45EST+5hours"
```

This command outputs `Sun Dec  8 16:16:45 EST 2019`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

GNU date very strangely parses the date, which makes it unreliable. The most reliable thing is to convert to seconds since epoch.

1. Convert the date to seconds.
2. Add 5 hours of seconds.
3. Convert the data to your favourite format.

```
date -d "@$(( $(date -d "2019-12-08 12:16:45" %s) + (5 * 60 * 60) ))"
```

> date -d "2019-12-08 12:16:45 +5 hours"

I guess the `+5` get's parsed as the timezone. So if you are in a timezone `+5` and want `EST`, then you need to substact 5 hours for the timezone and 4 hours for current EST time. The `hours` get's ignored.

Comment: Thanks!  I just determined the same thing!  If I add EST, I get the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

Add EST to the date & time string will give the correct answer.

I found it worthwhile to get the timezone and offset like so:

```
dateInfo=$(date +"%Z %z")
dateTZ=${dateInfo:0:3}
dateOffset="+"${dateInfo:5:2}
```

Then use them in the conversion code:

```
DATE=$(date -d "$CDATE1 $dateTZ $dateOffset hours" +%Y%m%d)
```

(where CDATE1 was parsed from a file's creation date as date & time)